# Change the value of a variable each time another variable changes

Tags: java, string, loops, variables, int

I am currently making a text adventure game in Java, but I have come across a problem:

I need the value of a `String` variable to change each time the value of a particular `int` variable changes.
I want the program to perform this task (then continue where it left off) each time the value of an `int` variable changes:

```
if (enemyposition == 1) {
    enemyp = "in front of you";
}
else if (enemyposition == 2) {
    enemyp = "behind you";
}
else if (enemyposition == 3) {
    enemyp = "to your left";
}
else if (enemyposition == 4) {
    enemyp = "to your right";
}
else {
    enemyp = "WOAH";
}
```

Thanks! :D

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: It is maybe easier to do this calculation whenever you need the value of `enemyp` rather than continuously.

Comment: my question is: pls halp

Answer (score 2):

You could make the code much shorter using an array.

```
String[] message = {"WOAH", // 0
                    "in front of you", // 1
                     "behind you", // 2
                     "to your left", // 3
                     "to your right"}; // 4
enemyp = (enemyposition > 0 && enemyposition < 5) ? message[enemyposition] : 
                                                    message[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The question you're asking *sounds* like it might be answerable by creating a class to hold the `enemyposition` integer.  Add a "setter" method to your class to set the integer.  You can write your setter method so that when the integer is set, it also sets up a string.  Then write a "getter" method to retrieve the string.  That's one common way of making sure two variables change together.

```
public class EnemyPosition {
    private int enemyposition;
    private String enemyp;
    public void setPosition(int n) { 
        enemyposition = n;
        enemyp = [adapt your code to set this based on the position]
    }
    public String getEnemyp() { 
         return enemyp;
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are a lot of details missing, but you get the idea.  Then instead of `int enemyposition` in the rest of your code, use `EnemyPosition enemyposition = new EnemyPosition()`, and use the `setPosition` method instead of assigning to it.

That's not the only solution (an array or `Map` that maps integers to strings may be good enough), but it's one OOP way to do things.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to implement that now, and let you know how it goes. :D